# Как запустить SetInterval при наличии одного класса и остановить при появлении другого?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть `<div class="myclass" style="width: 26px; height: 28px">` Мне нужно запустить SetInterval когда class="myclass". Потом появляется `class="myclass _my"` и выглядит это так `<div class="myclass _my" style="width: 26px; height: 28px">` Как остановить запущенный  SetInterval при появлении `class="myclass _my"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let intervalId; // Переменная для хранения идентификатора интервала

function checkForMyClass() {
  const myClassElement = document.querySelector('.myclass');
  const myMyClassElement = document.querySelector('.myclass._my');

  if (myClassElement && !myMyClassElement) {
    // Если есть элемент с классом "myclass" и нет элемента с классом "myclass _my"
    // Запускаем SetInterval, если он еще не запущен
    if (!intervalId) {
      intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        // Ваш код, который нужно выполнить периодически
        console.log('SetInterval запущен');
     }, 1000); // Здесь 1000 - интервал в миллисекундах (1 секунда)
   }
 } else if (intervalId) {
    // Если есть элемент с классом "myclass _my" и SetInterval запущен, останавливаем его
   clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    console.log('SetInterval остановлен');
  }
}

// Вызываем функцию checkForMyClass периодически для проверки наличия классов
setInterval(checkForMyClass, 1000);
```

В этом коде используется setInterval, чтобы проверять наличие класса "myclass" и его комбинации с "myclass _my". Если элемент с классом "myclass" существует и элемент с классом "myclass _my" не существует, setInterval будет запущен. Как только появляется элемент с классом "myclass _my", setInterval будет остановлен.

Comment: здравствуйте. А как можно функцию checkForMyClass запускать с кнопки и останавливать? То есть нажал на кнопку проверка на наличие классов идёт каждую секунду, второй раз нажимаешь на кнопку и и проверка прекращается.  Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: @Иван Здравствуйте! Для вашего вопроса сделал отдельно ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> А как можно функцию checkForMyClass запускать с кнопки и останавливать?... [Иван](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/571376/%d0%98%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd)

```js
let intervalId;
let isChecking = false;
const button = document.getElementById('startStopButton');
const myClassElement = document.querySelector('.myclass');

function checkForMyClass() {
    if (!isChecking) {
        if (myClassElement) {
            intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                console.log('SetInterval запущен');
            }, 1000);
            isChecking = true;
            button.textContent = 'Stop Checking';
        }
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
        isChecking = false;
        console.log('SetInterval остановлен');
        button.textContent = 'Start Checking';
    }
}


button.addEventListener('click', checkForMyClass);
```

```css
.myclass {
    width: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="startStopButton">Start Checking</button>
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Этот код использует флаг isChecking, чтобы отслеживать, запущена ли уже проверка на наличие класса и при клике на кнопку она будет запускать или останавливать проверку в зависимости от текущего состояния.

Comment: спасибо, да, кнопка то, что надо. А вот сама функция checkForMyClass не то, в первом ответе мне подходила идеальна. А можно, что-бы  функция checkForMyClass не изменялась, то есть , была такая как в ответе один, а кнопка из второго ответа?

Comment: @Иван исправил код, теперь по клику на кнопку если есть в наличии класс запускаеться SetInterval и по клику на кнопку останавливаеться

Comment: Dovgal Dima, я уже наверное надоел?) Код работает, но я думал , что проверка будет останавливаться при обнаружении класса, как в первом ответе. То есть, я кнопку нажимаю пошла провека, кнопку нажимаю повторно, проверка прекращается. Это есть. А ещё нужно что-бы  я нажимаю на кнопку пошла проверка, класс нашёлся и провека остановилась.

Comment: @Иван, здравствуйте! Для вашего вопроса сделал отдельно еще один ответ.

Comment: Dovgal Dima, спасибо!!! Очень помогли.

Comment: @Иван, рад был помочь!))

Answer (score 0):

> А ещё нужно что-бы я нажимаю на кнопку пошла проверка, класс нашёлся и провека остановилась. - [Иван](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/571376/%d0%98%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd)

```js
let intervalId;
let isChecking = false;
const button = document.getElementById('startStopButton');
const myClassElement = document.querySelector('.myclass');

function checkForMyClass() {
    if (!isChecking) {
        if (myClassElement) {
            intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                console.log('SetInterval запущен');
                if (document.querySelector('.myclass')) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    intervalId = null;
                    isChecking = false;
                    console.log('SetInterval остановлен');
                    button.textContent = 'Start Checking';
                }
            }, 1000);
            isChecking = true;
            button.textContent = 'Stop Checking';
        }
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
        isChecking = false;
        console.log('SetInterval остановлен');
        button.textContent = 'Start Checking';
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', checkForMyClass);
```

```css
.myclass {
    width: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="startStopButton">Start Checking</button>
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Этот код будет запускать setInterval, который каждую секунду будет проверять, существует ли элемент с классом myclass, когда этот элемент найден, интервал будет очищен, и проверка остановится.